# Exists lock-free hash tables that preserves insertion order?

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable, lock-free

I'm trying to optimize a library in which I use a lock-based hash table. 
One way to do it is to substitute that lock-based structure with a lock-free one.

I found some algorithms about, and I decided to implement in C using this paper: [Split-ordered lists: lock-free extensible hash tables](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~dcm/Teaching/COT4810-Spring2011/Literature/SplitOrderedLists.pdf)

The problem is that this kind of structure does not preserve the insertion order of the elements, and I need this feature for two reasons:

1) to get the next element to the current one (in accordance with insertion order and not in hashkey order),

2) to replace old entries (with new ones) when the maximum number of elements in the ht is reached. This because I use the hash table like a buffer, and I want to take its size fixed.

So I ask you, all lock-free hash table's implementations suffers from this "lack-of-insertion-order" issue? Or there is a solution?

Comment: If you can build a lock-free hash table that does not preserve insertion order, and you can build a lock-free "increment this counter", then on each insert you can increment the count, and store <key,counter> pairs and that by definition remembers order.   Your next question is probably, "... and how does one enumerate keys in insertion order efficiently?"  Dunno; maybe you can associate a dynamic array that maps insert-order indexes to keys.  But you have a proof that your original question has a "yes" answer.

Comment: If you need to preserve insertion order, then perhaps a hash table (lock-free or otherwise) is not the right data structure. A simple linked list, queue or deque might be better.

Comment: Hash tables have their nice properties because they **never** maintain order.

Comment: @IraBaxter you're right. But now the question is: in terms of performance, it's better using one good lock-based hash table or more than one lock-free ht (one for key/values and one for key/order)? Your solution decrease performance because in addition to Insert, it's needed another atomic operation (Increment). Also the order may not be preserved at all: in between this two operations, another thread may have entered an element to the ht, breaking the order.

Comment: Are you certain that the hash table is the bottleneck in your library? And if so, are you certain that the lock is the culprit?

Comment: @JimMischel certainly it's not the only, but for now I'm focusing on this element of my code, and I'm trying to understand if there is a way to optimize overall performance substituting lock-based with lock-free hashtable (getting rid of all that r/w locks).

Comment: My point is that, as you've discovered, writing lock-free code is difficult. It makes no sense unless you're certain that the lock is actually a performance problem. Considering that an uncontended lock takes less than 50 nanoseconds on modern hardware, it's very often not the bottleneck. If your threads aren't lining up behind the lock(s), then removing the locks probably isn't going to help much.

Answer (score 1):

If memory isn't an issue, a simple way to implement this is by using an atomic reference. Modifications will copy the internal data structure, make the changes and then update the reference.

In a simple implementation, that means the last write wins and all other writes are "ignored". For more complex cases, you add a locking structure in the reference which allows to queue write operations.

So you pay with another level of indirection but get a very simple way to swap data structures and algorithms.

Since this approach works with any algorithm, you can select one which preserves order.

Comment: Definitely it's a good solution. By the way I was wondering if there is an improvement to what I'm using (lock-free hashtable), without making too many changes.